# Adding birthday to a contact creates 2 entries after sync

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a very weired problem with my app while I try to add a birthday event on a picked contact.
My code for this is:

```
int mret = np2.getValue()+1;
ContentResolver cr = v.getContext().getContentResolver();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY);
if (boolyear == true) {
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, np3.getValue() + "-" + mret + "-" + np1.getValue());
} else {
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, "0000-" + mret + "-" + np1.getValue());
}
Uri bduri= null;
try {
    bduri= cr.insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,values);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

The above code works fine as it creates the birthday event but a few seconds later appears a second birthday entry which possibly is a result of sync as it happens only if there is an Internet connection.

This is not a problem of the device because other apps downloaded from Play Store work as expected. It's only my app that creates double birthday entries.

Why is this happening and how to fix that?
Thank you in advance.

---

**UPDATE**: I managed to fix it. The problem was the date format. All values (day and month) must be in a two-digit format. E.g. "1980-07-01", not "1980-7-1".

Comment: you should put your solution as an answer, and accept it so the question will be marked as answered

Comment: I didn't know thay. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it. The problem was the date format. All values (day and month) must be in a two-digit format. E.g. "1980-07-01", not "1980-7-1".

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using a Sync Adapter to interface with the Calendar.

The Sync Adapter has two important methods:

onPerformSync(...), and onSyncCanceled(...)

onPerformSync is called whenever you make a ContentResolver.requestSync call or if automatic sync is set to true.

While executing, onPerformSync can be interrupted by Android. This can happen if the device is running low on resources of if your app is not in the foreground anymore.

When interupted, the Sync Adapter will stop execution where it's at and will call onSyncCanceled. The default behavior of the Sync Adapter is to retry the failed sync messages the first chance it gets. So if your app manages to grab onto OS resources again, it will replay the interrupted sync message.

It is possible that some of your messages are being fully processed and, just before onPerformSync is about to complete, the Sync Adapter is interrupted. At this point you managed to save the event, however, the Sync Adapter believes that the sync failed, and therefore will replay the same message again the next time it tries to sync.

I am not sure if you are syncing one event at a time so I can't offer a definitive solution. However, what you can do is change the default behaviour of the Sync Adapter to stop it from replaying "failed" messages.

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
...
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_DO_NOT_RETRY, true);
CalendarConstants.AUTHORITY, true);
ContentResolver.requestSync(mAccount, CalendarConstants.AUTHORITY, extras);
```

In OnSyncCanceled, you can do some light checks to make sure the message succeeded, i.e. is present in the calendar's events table. If not, then manually replay it. If it is present, the SyncAdapter will simply move on to the next message, and you won't get any duplicates.

Alternatively, you could make sure all operations within onPerformSync are atomic.

Comment: I don't want to make a Calendar event but an entry to a picked contact. As you can see in my code all task is done with ContactsContract, not calendar.